# Why is threadID unique?

Tags: c, pthreads

I've used POSIX threads a few times in C and I never thought about this until the other day: why is the variable taken from `arg` given to `pthread_create()` private, given that all the threads call the same function when they start and run the same code to initialise the same variable (most likely a thread ID)? For example, the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* threadMethod(void* arg)
{
    int threadID = (int) arg;
    printf("Thread %d reporting in\n", threadID);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadMethod, (void*) i);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

`threadID` has a unique value to each thread but I don't understand why, given that it's the same variable in the same method that all threads execute. Shouldn't threads be overwriting each others' value of it? I think it's something to do with stacks. Could someone please clarify what exactly is going on here?

Comment: casting from int to void* back to int is unorthodox, but should work if pointers aren't smaller than ints. What do you mean by 'private' ?

Comment: It's the same method that all threads are working with, so if one thread changes the value of the variable `threadID`, shouldn't all threads observe this change?

Comment: you are passing by value (but casted to pointer)

Comment: Why does that matter? It's the same variable in the same function which all threads read from and write to.

Comment: method calls happen either in a register, or on the stack, as a copied value

Comment: threadID (a [*local variable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable)) isn't "private" (other than being a *local variable*, which is appropriate here) - please clarify the title. The question would be slightly (but not really) more interesting if it were a global variable. The warnings are not related to the scope of the *local variable* threadID.

Comment: Each time `threadMethod()` executes, each instance of that function running will get its own separate version of `threadID`. Your idea that "it's the same variable in the same function which all threads read from and write to" is flawed. All functions work this way in C. In the absence of threads, a function can call itself and essentially be executing more than once at the same time, and in this instance, too, you will end up with multiple versions of the local variables, as many as there are instances of the function executing.

Comment: For the update .. why *wouldn't* the value (?) be unique per thread? The code is passing in a different *value* (incremented in the loop, so it's not really a "thread ID") to each thread as initialization data.

Comment: @Doddy It is not the same variable in all the functions. First, each thread has its own stack, so all local variables in the thread function exists separately for each thread. Secondly, `(void*) i` will copy `i` into the last argument of your thread function - C always passes arguments by value, (It'll have the type `void*` instead of an `int`, which will be somewhat ok on posix platforms, but is generally not ok in C). Note that this is quite different from passing a pointer to `i` such as `(void*)&i`

Comment: @user2864740 because it's got nothing to do with whether it's by value or by reference. I'm asking why one thread writing to it doesn't overwrite it for the other threads.

Comment: The way to think about it is whenever a statement like `int threadID;` executes, the program goes out and grabs four new bytes (if `int` uses four bytes on your system) and makes a new `int` out of it. If you run that function 10 times, then it'll execute that statement 10 times and create 10 new `int`s, all using different four-byte blocks of memory. At the end of the function, these `int`s will be destroyed and the memory will be released. It does usually happen on the stack, but that's not really important to understanding, just that you get a new `int` every time that statement runs.

Comment: @Doddy Why would it? This concept, with a local variable, not inherently different than if the method is recursively called: "the [*local variable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) lives somewhere else". In this case it just happens to be in a different thread's "stack" (just as how each thread knows how to resume code, can isolate register usage, etc ..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question should be, "Why do all 8 thread get their own argument"
(private means something else)

The answer to that is, that you are passing by value.
The **content** of the variable is copied into a register
(or the stack depending on calling convention)
and is then copied further into the local argument variable
(arg), witch lives in thread-local memory.

Answer (score 0):

pthread_create is a C function so there is no concept of private. The reason why the argument to your thread function is a "void*" is because void* is a generic pointer that can point to any type of memory. What that memory is, is between the thread function and the function creating the thread. You are free to use this for a threadId but it really can be anything. Since each thread may be created using a different startup function and using different data.

The reason for the warning is that void* is 64 bits on a 64 bit machine but in is typically 32 bits. The compiler is warning you that you may lose data in the cast. Using a `size_t` instead of an `int` should remove the warning.